# Peano axioms and meaning of successor map in Jacobson's Basic Algebra I

Tags: peano-axioms

From Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I* on P. 16, the Peano axioms are stated as:

1. $0 \neq a^+$ for any $a$ (that is, $0$ is not in the image of $\mathbb{N}$ under $a \to a^+$).
2. $a\to a^{+}$ is injective.
3. (Axiom of induction). Any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which contains $0$ and contains the successor of every element in the given subset coincides with $\mathbb{N}$.

First, $a$ does not seem to be defined to be anything (at least from what I can see on the current and previous page), though it seems like it is supposed to be representing some arbitrary element in $\mathbb{N}$? It is not clear. So my first question is what is the notation $a$ and $a^+$ referencing?

The other question I have is regarding that of the successor map. Why do I need two axioms for a map? Why can I not just point to the mapping $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by $f(n) = n+1$. When I think more about it, couldn't I define the map to be $f(n) = n+k$, where $k$ is a positive integer? What is the relation of the axiomatization to the successor map? Does the successor map not exist without an axiomatization?

**Additional Context**

There are only two other places where $a$ is mentioned before this, which is on P.15 of the text:
"For example, in a structure $S$ in which an associative binary composition and a unit are defined, any element $a \in S$ defines a map $n \to a^n$ where $a^0=1, a^1 = a,$ and $a^k = a^{k-1}a$."

"From this point of view, we begin with a non-vacuous set $\mathbb{N}$, a particular element of $\mathbb{N}$ designated as $0$ and a map $a \to a^+$ of $\mathbb{N}$ to itself, called the *successor*
map."

Comment: Please link or copy all the relevant information about Peano axioms from Jacobson. Surely he has something like "there is a set $A$ and a map $a \mapsto a^+$ such that..."

Comment: Here is a pdf which is the same as the text I have: http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Jacobson-Basic_algebra_I%20(1).pdf

Comment: Yes that's a link. But it is to the entire text. For questions here, I think users would appreciate more effort to summarize relevant definitions than simply to link to a large pdf file.

Comment: I felt it was less cumbersome to link (the pages are 15 and 16, towards the beginning) than to either type out the entire section or guess at what I missed. I typed out what I believed was relevant, I am asking for help because I do not know what is relevant beyond this and because to the best of my knowledge there was not a previous definition of $a$.

Comment: ricard: OK I'll try to check it when I get time. Hopefully someone here can respond who has a copy of Jacobson. Good luck.

Comment: Richard: I found the basic setup in the second paragraph of section 0.4 [The natural numbers]. That explanation is actually in the same paragraph from which you quote the rules.  Also Gerry Myerson has outlined things in his answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Peano axioms are a way to *define* the natural numbers; to introduce the concepts of addition when trying to define the natural numbers would be circular.

So: "for any $a$" means "for any $a$ in $\bf N$". It is not assumed that $\bf N$ has any structure or properties other than those we can prove from the Peano axioms. After we have proved a few theorems, we can identify $a^+$ with $a+1$, but when we're just getting started, we don't have any "$+$" and we don't have any "$1$".